# What is inside SVM XML classifier file?

Tags: xml, opencv, svm

I made bag of visual words and trained it using SVM. After training I saved classifier file to an xml file. I want to know what is inside this file. That would be perfect if someone could explain me what are these confusing complex numbers? For instance in one of the classifier I have these numbers listed as one of the support vectors

```
 0. 0. 0. 0. 7.14285718e-03 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 7.14285718e-03
  0. 0. 7.14285718e-03 0. 0. 0. 7.14285718e-03 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
  7.14285718e-03 0. 0. 0. 0. 7.14285718e-03 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
  0. 0. 7.14285718e-03 7.14285718e-03 7.14285718e-03 0. 0. 0.
  7.14285718e-03 7.14285718e-03 7.14285718e-03 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
  0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 7.14285718e-03 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 7.14285718e-03 0. 0.
  7.14285718e-03 0. 7.14285718e-03 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 7.14285718e-03 0.
  0. 7.14285718e-03 0. 0. 1.42857144e-02 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
  0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 7.14285718e-03 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
  7.14285718e-03 7.14285718e-03 0. 0. 0. 7.14285718e-03 0. 0.
  7.14285718e-03 0. 7.14285718e-03 0. 0. 0. 7.14285718e-03 0. 0. 0.
  0. 7.14285718e-03 7.14285718e-03 1.42857144e-02 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
  0. 7.14285718e-03 7.14285718e-03 0. 0. 7.14285718e-03 0. 0. 0. 0.
  0. 0. 0. 7.14285718e-03 7.14285718e-03 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
  7.14285718e-03 7.14285718e-03 0. 0. 0. 0. 7.14285718e-03 0. 0.
  7.14285718e-03 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 7.14285718e-03 7.14285718e-03 0.
  0. 0. 0. 7.14285718e-03 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.42857144e-02 0.
  7.14285718e-03 7.14285718e-03 0. 0. 7.14285718e-03 7.14285718e-03
  7.14285718e-03 0. 0. 0. 7.14285718e-03 0. 7.14285718e-03 0.
  7.14285718e-03 0. 0. 0. 7.14285718e-03 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
  0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 7.14285718e-03 7.14285718e-03 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
  0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.42857144e-02 0. 0. 0.
  7.14285718e-03 7.14285718e-03 7.14285718e-03 0. 0. 7.14285718e-03
  0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 7.14285718e-03 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.42857144e-02
  0. 7.14285718e-03 7.14285718e-03 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
  7.14285718e-03 0. 7.14285718e-03 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
  7.14285718e-03 1.42857144e-02 7.14285718e-03 0. 0. 0.
  7.14285718e-03 7.14285718e-03 0. 7.14285718e-03 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
  0. 0. 0. 0. 7.14285718e-03 0. 0. 0. 7.14285718e-03 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
  0. 0. 0. 7.14285718e-03 0. 0. 7.14285718e-03 0. 0. 0.
  7.14285718e-03 1.42857144e-02 0. 0. 7.14285718e-03 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
  7.14285718e-03 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 7.14285718e-03 0. 1.42857144e-02
  7.14285718e-03 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 7.14285718e-03 0.
  7.14285718e-03 0. 7.14285718e-03 0. 0. 0. 7.14285718e-03 0. 0. 0.
  0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 7.14285718e-03 7.14285718e-03 0.
  7.14285718e-03 0. 7.14285718e-03 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.42857144e-02 0.
  0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 7.14285718e-03 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
  7.14285718e-03 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
  0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 7.14285718e-03 0. 0. 0. 7.14285718e-03 0. 0.
  0. 0. 0. 7.14285718e-03 0. 0. 7.14285718e-03 7.14285718e-03 0.
  7.14285718e-03 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 7.14285718e-03 0. 0.
  0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 7.14285718e-03 7.14285718e-03 0. 0. 0.
  7.14285718e-03 0. 0. 7.14285718e-03 0. 0. 7.14285718e-03 0.
  7.14285718e-03 0. 0. 0. 7.14285718e-03 1.42857144e-02
  7.14285718e-03 0. 7.14285718e-03 7.14285718e-03 0. 7.14285718e-03
  0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 7.14285718e-03 7.14285718e-03 0. 0.
  7.14285718e-03 7.14285718e-03 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
  7.14285718e-03 0. 1.42857144e-02 0. 0. 7.14285718e-03 0. 0.
  7.14285718e-03 7.14285718e-03 0. 7.14285718e-03 7.14285718e-03 0.
  0. 7.14285718e-03 0. 0. 7.14285718e-03 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
  0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 7.14285718e-03 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 7.14285718e-03 0.
  0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 7.14285718e-03 0.
  7.14285718e-03 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
  7.14285718e-03 0.</_>
```

I also have some numbers listed as decision function

```
 <_>
  <sv_count>160</sv_count>
  <rho>6.8452455347574559e-01</rho>
  <alpha>
    2.5423138988157837e+02 4.5359710671544804e+01
    4.7925099613211181e+01 3.2497094934516078e+01
    2.4983673109354024e+02 2.0186724271830130e+00
    4.9541532560346980e+01 1.9258206475108761e+02
    1.4208655744375281e+02 2.0711626640754659e+02
    1.2068417868722047e+02 1.3573973539317768e+01
    5.5489123127143664e+01 9.7180296858566976e+01
    6.9886513829497147e+01 1.6371164919246954e+01
    3.1642406354083249e+01 2.5886527876799857e+02
    3.1250000000000000e+02 3.1250000000000000e+02
    2.0771926734227043e+02 4.2495168884268978e+01
    2.8453561492315282e+02 1.1405394481820327e+01
    1.7741953230246492e+02 9.2973753188366530e+01
    3.9712931629884940e+00 9.0291607882962168e+01
    3.1546308765559861e+01 3.1250000000000000e+02
    1.4896568695951177e+02 1.5306466156082442e+02
    2.7305921645345398e+02 3.1250000000000000e+02
    1.4892283547123927e+02 4.7594479073169801e+01
    2.1824299237008475e+02 2.4829756411437891e+01
    3.1976656407063476e+01 5.6938028381102022e+01
    3.1250000000000000e+02 2.5953680249873128e+02
    1.0002648018172249e+02 2.5157934309570987e+02
    1.7741103715377861e+01 1.9992699841501917e+01
    8.6202148931839787e+01 1.0392782855617838e+02
    3.1250000000000000e+02 7.6663908473776402e+01
    5.5675806743350947e+01 3.1250000000000000e+02
    7.3328033730960257e+01 6.5586061236933034e+01
    4.2039699007673583e+01 7.5370218914539429e+00
    1.7203879419077174e+02 4.2944551804786656e+01
    1.6962172789493428e+02 6.9676253907360163e+01
    2.2036375754735451e+02 1.9013513283743939e+02
    2.1175310816726309e+02 1.1501452645915194e+02
    9.3145425905269946e+01 1.1792778507058536e+01
    3.1250000000000000e+02 2.2680096047467424e+02
    3.1250000000000000e+02 7.6728278490255576e+01
    2.0175148545806369e+01 1.1273255229456623e+02
    2.1795882740597577e+02 2.4400361256876141e+02
    1.2123557815356189e+02 1.5920223919570387e+02
    7.7440259533867632e+01 3.1250000000000000e+02
    -1.8112193734535182e+02 -6.9153767437005982e+01
    -3.1250000000000000e+02 -3.1250000000000000e+02
    -1.4495109182072518e+01 -8.9557554159927960e+01
    -7.1916123157995997e+01 -2.4218527642086951e+02
    -1.7211054184341103e+02 -2.3748462041725261e+01
    -1.8462608637511977e+02 -2.2874954256233488e+02
    -7.2542014531887006e+01 -1.8997108501002415e+02
    -1.5598282505321716e+01 -5.5723745769954917e+01
    -5.2802598904913609e+01 -1.3013028628143746e+02
    -1.2124556881272166e+02 -1.1423168465471257e+02
    -5.2147128197400150e+01 -2.1216778063124082e+02
    -1.5000985328856076e-01 -1.7754679880386032e+01
    -1.1823360915217981e+02 -3.4861851956600006e+01
    -2.3578140235546104e+02 -1.3001303548621669e+02
    -4.6736763318124133e+01 -8.5950845203580101e+01
    -4.1035785728939921e+01 -3.1250000000000000e+02
    -8.8795368804725229e+01 -5.1385733643393223e+01
    -1.8731464905569453e+02 -6.4504100104803541e+01
    -9.3282340087581758e+01 -1.9980840892775740e+02
    -3.1903639756172673e+01 -2.7071173159041695e+01
    -1.2731899125431256e+02 -2.3635950086980486e+02
    -1.3187967454395482e+02 -1.5046577609246560e+02
    -1.7451647263470295e+02 -3.2916479760248947e+01
    -6.1305721034966489e+01 -6.2939162691432998e+01
    -4.5532244525447773e+01 -1.2147281278044319e+02
    -2.3806419646114563e+02 -7.1052243132435734e+01
    -1.0259059168292725e+02 -1.5751096262864070e+02
    -1.1956437113909620e+02 -1.4033869361185694e+02
    -1.9355483203613363e+02 -2.1442805317743975e+02
    -3.1250000000000000e+02 -8.7323058651175728e+01
    -7.7141310535231227e+01 -2.6142074888957346e+01
    -1.5777296612468865e+02 -4.4918113905201572e+01
    -9.4008234073480864e+01 -1.6906602934353973e+02
    -3.9150799407684666e+01 -1.1500702631407735e+02
    -3.1250000000000000e+02 -1.3655423586611803e+02
    -2.3671839466119775e+02 -2.9748423709122022e+02
    -2.2222775915092885e+01 -2.5321356872483855e+02
    -3.1250000000000000e+02 -1.2565985069323030e+02
    -8.0582560246929845e+01 -2.5479938786542269e+02
    -3.0449808108987465e+01 -2.6231027402499296e+02
    -1.6509634709133155e+02 -8.9200955788667031e+01</alpha>
  <index>
```

Obviously the first one is a support vector and the second one is a decision function. But the question is that what are these numbers represented for? Are there starting point? ending point? ditection? angle? different parameters for the kernel? if so in what aspects they were stored? It should be added that I used RBF kernel for inserted examples. (I need these information to be able to draw a plot form it) like this one:
[RBF Kernel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLoW8.png)
many thanks in advance

Comment: are those the alphas of this formula? https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/59477

Comment: I don't know! :( It seems there are. But I want to be sure..